# how would I change a window handles via edit control box in an mfc application?

Tags: c++, mfc, editcontrol

I have made a small program (using mfc) that edits a text box in another one of my applications, but every time I want to use my program I have to edit the following:

```
HWND editbox = (HWND)0x0000000;
```

to whatever the new handle is using winspy++, I would like to know how I would go about adding another text box with a button so I can add in the new value, click the button, and it is updated so I no longer have to keep rebuilding my application with the new handle.

Comment: Instead of replacing one hack with another, you should consider using the right tool: [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can read the contents of an edit control using

```
GetDlgItemText(hDlg, ID_THE_EDIT_CONTROL, buffer, buffersize);
```

Then convert the string in buffer to an unsigned int for use as the HWND.